# Turn a model into a specular light source

Tags: wpf, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

I have 2 models. One is a vehicle, the other is a series of tube lights.  I want to be able to see only the specular reflections of the tube lights on the vehicle.

How can I turn the model of lights into a light source?  I tried giving it an emissive material, but then found that an emissive material will not illuminate other figures.